# getting the translated version of current url token

Tags: 8, tokens

In D8, with the usual translation modules enabled, I have a custom pop-up to change language on our site. Currently, it contains a link and text, like this:

```
<p><a href="/en-us[current-page:url:alias]">EN</a> | <a href="/es-us[current-page:url:alias]">ES</a></p>
```

This would work, except that the link of the translated page is different.

Example. If I'm on the English page, "website.com/contact-us" and change my language to Spanish, the page will load "website.com/es-us/contact-us" ... which does not exist. It's a 404 error

But that is incorrect. The Spanish version is correctly spelled 'contáctenos"
So, I want the Spanish user to go to "website.com/es-us/contactenos.

Is there a way to do this with the tokens? Or another approach? Some way to know to send the user to the Spanish url translation of the page

Thank you!

Comment: The straight forward way would be using core's "Language Switcher" block.

Comment: I can't in this case, I need a large lightbox screen that is much more involved than the language switcher dropdown field block can handle, from what I've been able to determine so far